# C# await udpClient.ReceiveAsync() fails and terminates program

Tags: c#, async-await, udpclient

I'm running a C# console application with .NET 4.5.1. When I run the following function the udpClient.ReceiveAsync() call below silently terminates the program with no exception.  How do I debug this?

```
   public async void Run()
    {
        try
        {
            var armIpAddress = IPAddress.Parse("239.1.11.1");
            using (var udpClient = new UdpClient())
            {
                udpClient.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
                var ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 12020);
                udpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
                udpClient.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
                udpClient.Client.Bind(ipEndPoint);
                udpClient.JoinMulticastGroup(armIpAddress);

                while (true)
                {
                    var result = await udpClient.ReceiveAsync();
                    //...
                }
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's calling `Run` and why is this `async void` rather than `async Task`? That's the main source of untracability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call to `await udpClient.ReceiveAsync()` is not terminating the program nor it is silently failing.

Given that this is happening, I assume you have something like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ...
    Run();
}
```

In an `async void` method, control is returned to the parent as soon as an `await` call is reached, so the flow of the program would be something like:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ...
    var armIpAddress = IPAddress.Parse("239.1.11.1");
    using (var udpClient = new UdpClient())
    {
        udpClient.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
        .......

        while (true)
        {
            return; 
        }
    }
}
```

So the program ends due to no further blocking code.

For this to work as you would expect, change the code to this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ...
    Run().Wait();
}

public async Task Run() { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the calling method, but with the given infomation, I would suggest the following [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) that has best practices around async await by @Stephen Cleary

It says to avoid `async void` and I am pasting an excerpt here from the article for quick reference

> 1. Async void methods can wreak havoc if the caller isn’t expecting them to be async. When the return type is Task, the caller knows it’s
>      dealing with a future operation; when the return type is void, the
>      caller might assume the method is complete by the time it returns.
>      This problem can crop up in many unexpected ways.
>
>    2. Exceptions from an Async Void Method Can’t Be Caught with Catch